# How to expose imported components?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm very new to python, and am using Python 3.5

I have a file structure like this:

```
main.py
MyModule/
MyModule/__init__.py
MyModule/component.py
MyModule/component/
MyModule/component/__init__.py      # blank
MyModule/component/subcomponent.py
```

In some script I would like to be able to use `MyModule.component.subcomponent.myfunc()` using either of these two approaches:

```
import MyModule.component
result = MyModule.component.subcomponent.myfunc()
```

or

```
import MyModule.component.subcomponent
result = MyModule.component.subcomponent.myfunc()
```

I tried making my `./MyModule/component.py` have the following, but it didn't work:

```
# This didn't expose the subcomponent stuff
from MyModule.component.subcomponent import *

# I tried this too, but it also didn't work
subcomponent = MyModule.component.subcomponent
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted?  It's a valid question, not overly specific or opinionated.  Anyone coming from another language that doesn't use this paradigm could have the same question.  Whoever down-voted it, please let me know so I can improve my questions in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a name conflict. You can't have both `component.py` *and* a `component` package. When Python imports `MyModule.component` it'll either find the `component.py` module ***or*** the `component/__init__.py` package. **You can't have both**.

On my Python 3.7 setup on OS X, packages win:

```
$ mkdir -p demopackage/nested
$ cat > demopackage/nested.py <<EOF
> print('This is the nested.py module file')
> EOF
$ cat > demopackage/nested/__init__.py <<EOF
> print('This is the nested/__init__.py package file')
> EOF
$ python3.7 -c 'import demopackage.nested'
This is the nested/__init__.py package file
```

which would mean your `component.py` file is never even executed.

Move the `component.py` contents into `component/__init__.py` and import your submodules there. When you import a submodule of a package, that module automatically becomes an attribute.

So all you need to do is remove `component.py`, and then you can use

```
import MyModule.component.subcomponent
```

anywhere, at which point `import MyModule.component` will suffice to be able to reach `MyModule.component.subcomponent.myfunc()`.

See the [*Submodules* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) of the Python reference documentation on the import system:

> When a submodule is loaded *[...]* a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.

I'd use package-relative imports at the top of your `MyModule/component/__init__.py` file:

```
from . import submodule
```

to ensure that the submodule is loaded when you import `MyModule.component`.

Comment: Ahh, it wasn't clear to me that the `__init__.py`  was the package definition.  The most common way I had seen it discussed was as a *signifier* of a package to Python, and as a place where some package pre-processing code could be run.  It's helpful to understand that it also carries with it the implicit meaning of a package definition file.  This is (maybe?) the first language I've used where this is not allowed, so it didn't even occur to me.